# PostgreSQL, splitting to rows and recognizing the first part

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
id SERIAL, 
values TEXT);

INSERT INTO t1 (values) 
VALUES ('T815,T847'), ('F00,B4R,B4Z'), ('AS5,XX3'), ('G00');
```

like:

```
id|values
--------------
1 |T815,T847
2 |F00,B4R,B4Z
3 |AS5,XX3
4 |G00
```

I need to split the values in the values column on their own row and mark the first values, like this:

```
id|first|value
--------------
1 | yes | T815
1 |     | T84T
2 | yes | F00
2 |     | B4R
2 |     | B4Z
3 | yes | AS5
3 |     | XX3
4 | yes | G00
```

I can produce *id* and *value* with:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       regexp_split_to_table(t1.values, E',') 
FROM t1;
```

but how would I recognize and tag the first values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you can use a brute force method:

```
SELECT t1.id, value,
       (case when values like value || '%' then 'yes' end) as first
FROM (SELECT t1.id,  t1.values,
             regexp_split_to_table(t1.values, E',') as value
      FROM t1
     ) t1;
```

Comment: It's fine, thanks. Now reading your solution I realize I should've used names other than t1, value or values...